# Facebook Graph API and FQL gives error in PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to run FQL using graph api.

```
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=".$fql."&access_token=". $access_token;

$output = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

var_dump($output);
```

This gives an error

> `[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request`

If i copy and paste the contents of `$graph_url` in the browser, i get the expected results. So, I'm sure my access_token and fql query are correct.

Also, if i try to fetch the contents by

```
  $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=". $access_token;

  $output = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

  var_dump($output);
```

I don't get any errors but expected result. I'm not sure, what is missing in my fql query.

Comment: what's the contents of `$fql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best bet I can make is an urlencode issue.

Try this,

```
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=".urlencode($fql)."&access_token=". $access_token;
```